# PHP mysqli updating a blob value in table does nothing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I have a variable called $description that has a paragraph of information in it. Some of these descriptions are a sentence or 2, some are long, so im using blobs to save this instead of var char. This statement executes without a problem, but nothing actually gets saved. No errors reported.

```
$query = "UPDATE event SET description=? WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query))
{
    $null = NULL;
    $stmt -> bind_param("bi", $null, $id);
    $stmt -> send_long_data(0, $description);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

Is there something im missing?

Comment: Have you checked that $id is a valid ID that exists in the database?  In other words, is the WHERE clause actually matching a record?

Comment: Show us the actual SQL query that gets sent to the DB. Show us the results of that query if you run it from the mysql client. Showing us broken code with variables that are not known to us cannot help us fix the problem.

Comment: add `echo $stmt->error;` to the end of that to see what's going wrong with the execute.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding `b` as blob, try to refer to `s` as **string**